# mysql expanded output

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql, command-line

I'm coming from postgresql to mysql, curious if  mysql has an expanded output flag similar to that of postgresql?

ie: in psql I could **\x** to get expanded output

```
id | name
---+-----
 1 | foo
```

into

```
-[ Record ]------
id   | 1
name | foo
```

how can I do this in mysql?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

try `SELECT foo FROM bla\G` instead of `SELECT foo FROM bla;`